# Why Transform.position in 2D always returns 0,0,0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On clicking the button, I call the Shoot () function, which should create a bullet in the place of the character, but creates in the center of the scene.

At the Start() in the PlayerShooter code, I checked that it returns the correct trasform.position value, but when the button is pressed in the Shoot () function it returns 0,0,0

I figured out that bullet spawns on prefab's position, not on instantiated object from prefab position, how can i fix this?

Shoot code:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bullet;
    [SerializeField] private float _distanceMultiplier;
    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length > 1)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(_bullet.name, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Character moving script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D), typeof(CapsuleCollider2D))]
public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speepMoving, _speedRotation;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    private Vector2 _direction;
    private PhotonView _view;
    [HideInInspector] public FixedJoystick joystick;
    private void Start()
    {
        _view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_view.IsMine && PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length > 1)
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal * _speepMoving, joystick.Vertical * _speepMoving);
            RotatePlayer();
        }
    }
    private void RotatePlayer()
    {
        _direction = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
        if (_direction != Vector2.zero)
        {
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, _direction);
            _rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, toRotation, _speedRotation * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `PlayerShooter` attached to?

Comment: @Absinthe to Player object, PlayerMover also attached to Player object

Comment: Odd. I'm not familiar with `Photon` - what happens if you instantiate normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with this code:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bullet;
    [SerializeField] private float _distanceMultiplier;

    [HideInInspector] public Button shootButton;

    private void Start()
    {
        shootButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { Shoot(); });
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length > 1)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(_bullet.name, transform.position + transform.up * _distanceMultiplier, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```